# 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' nearly matches optional requirement 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' of protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, compiler-warnings, access-modifiers

I am working on an app where I have created modules for each feature of the app. I have to switch from one Module UI Controller to another Module UI Controller.

I have UIController in a Module and I mark that controller as *Public* access identifier as below

```
public class InterAccountTransferViewController: UIViewController {
   override public func viewDidLoad() {
    ......
    ......
   }
}
```

Above class also implements UITextField delegates in extension. When I created above class as Open access I am getting a warning on TextField delegates as  below

> Instance method 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' nearly matches optional
>   requirement 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' of protocol
>   'UITextFieldDelegate'

[image]

Now textfield delegates are not being called. When I tried to turn off a warning by making delegates as private, they are still not being called.

Please let me know how to silence these warnings & call the delegates as well.

Any idea or suggestion would be great. I am working on Xcode 10 with swift 4.2. Please let me know if I have to explain my question more.

Comment: Make sure about few points. - Did you attached delegates like self.textfield.delegate = self. - public class InterAccountTransferViewController: UIViewController,UItextFieldDelegate { } , - In above warning, click on yellow bar and it must suggesting something to update delegate method signature.

Comment: @Sakshi I have already tried but no success.

Comment: @RobertDresler I have already tried with at:objc but no effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With "Nearly matches", the compiler tells you two things:

1. It **doesn't match**: the method 'textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)' is not the same as the delegate method 'textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)'. This is in itself not a problem for the compiler, you just have a method with some name, and it doesn't know the name, so it's okay.
2. It **very much looks like** the delegate method 'textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)'. So the compiler can see that you probably intended this to be a delegate method, and it is telling you that, well, it did not work. What you have written is not a delegate method.

It's nice from the compiler that it tells you that there is a problem. It's not so nice that it doesn't explain what the problem is exactly.

**The problem is that your class has more visibility than the delegate method.** Your class is `public`, while your delegate method is just `internal` (because `internal` is the default, if you don't have an access specifier in your declaration.)

The fix is to give the delegate method a `public` access specifier too.

You have to change

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // ...
}
```

to

```
public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // ...
}
```

This will let the compiler know that the method is indeed intended to be a delegate method.

---

Bonus Content...

**How did I find the solution?** I reproduced the issue in Xcode. I clicked on the warning and read the Fixup: "Make 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' non-public to silence this warning". I clicked "Fix" and the line was changed to "private func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)". So I figured that maybe turning it `public` instead of `private` would help even more. I tried it, checked it, and it worked.

**Why does Swift even do this?** I'm not sure, but my guess is this: if a class is public, but the protocol method is internal, it would mean that an individual view controller object implements the protocol when you look from the perspective of the module. But since the protocol implementation is internal, the protocol method would be unavailable when looking from the perspective of outside modules, e.g. from UIKit. But this is not possible in the Objective C runtime, and even if it were possible, it would be bad. Silently making the protocol methods public or semi-public would be possible, but not very clean: e.g. one could make textFieldDidBeginEditing internal, but when you cast the object to a UITextFieldDelegate pseudo-object, you can suddenly call that method, which would also be surprising.

Comment: Very good explanation. Just a pity that I tries 2 hours to understand what happened before finding it.

Comment: I don’t get it. Why does both private and public work, but then internal doesn’t?!

Comment: @Honey: `private` doesn't really work. It just compiles. Only `public` works. Since the UITextFieldDelegate protocol is public, a conformance must be public too, so that everyone who can see the conformance can also call the method. If you make it `private` it's no longer a conformance, it's just a completely unrelated method that just has the same name as one of the UITextFieldDelegate methods.

Comment: so the compiler's suggestion is ultimately misleading. ie you saying 'It's not so nice that it doesn't explain what the problem is exactly.' should be more of 'It's not so nice that it's message is misleading'

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class InterAccountTransferViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Attach delegates 
    self.textfield.delegate = self
 }
   //TextField Delegate Method
   public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark your method also as `public`

```
public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **`public`** access modifier with your function like this.

```
public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     // do whatever you want
}
```